# How can I know this method of uikit relate to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have crash with `UITableView`

I see this method of UIKit call.

```
     CoreFoundation 
__exceptionPreprocess + 130
2    CoreFoundation 
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 230
3
___ 
__NotificationHistoryDataSource.m line 152
-[__NotificationHistoryDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
4
___ 
___MenuDataSource.m line 141
-[___MenuDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
5
UIKit   
-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 410
6
UIKit   
-[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1806
7
UIKit   
-[UITableView _visibleCells] + 24
8
UIKit   
-[UITableView _updateAnimationDidStop:finished:context:] + 1064
9
UIKit   
__46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke831 + 66
10
UIKit   
-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _sendDeferredCompletion:] + 66
```

How can I know what is Method of `UITableView` I have call?
Updated crash log

It here I have two table in table

menu:

```
case MenuSectionNotification:{
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;
       }
```

inherited from notification

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   {
self.mySection = section;
return [self.notificationList count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int row = [indexPath row];
    --NotificationCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:  [---NotificationCell identifier]];
    ---Notification* notification = nil;
    notification = [self.notificationList objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: What's the crash message?

Comment: some problem in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, paste code of this method.

Comment: Fatal Exception: NSRangeException *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array. I know this error and it happen when call cellforrowatindexpath. But I don't know where is call this function and make it crash. So i want see interface method of uitableview call function UIkit above

Comment: It doesn't matter where or why UITableView called your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  The problem is that you have an inconsistency between your data model and the number of rows returned by `numberOfRowsInSection`.  You should show the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    self.mySection = section;
    return [self.notificationList count];
    
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int row = [indexPath row];
    ---NotificationCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[---NotificationCell identifier]];
    ---Notification* notification = nil;
    notification = [self.notificationList objectAtIndex:row];

I think i don't make inconsistent here.

Comment: It is better if you edit your question to include the code there.  Your code does appear to be consistent, but there are two different tables referred to in your stack trace.  Also, how many sections do you have in your table view?  You do something with the section in numberOfRows, but not anywhere else.  Did you use an exception breakpoint to get the exact line

Comment: It might help to put an All Exception Breakpoint using the Break Point Navigation on the left hand side pane (click the + sign, add exception, it should default to All Exception). Run your app again, hopefully it triggers a breakpoint where the error is.